# Store graph nodes with edges in relational database

Tags: graph, relational-database, nodes, vertex, edges

what is the best way, how to store graph and edges is relational database? I work on school project where i need store cities and distance between them ... next i will be able to find shortest path between point A and point B.

My solution is:
Store cities in one table
**Nodes**(city_Id, city_name, ...)

and second table will represent graph edges with unique pair
**Edges**(cityA_Id, cityB_Id, distance, time)

Is it good way or exist something better? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine.  To prevent undirected edges from being recorded twice, I would ensure that cityA_Id < cityB_Id.